# 500 Error calling scalar database function from .net core 2.1

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to call a scalar function that I have in my database from my .NET Core 2.1 Web API to get an employee's director; the function in my database expects the employee id as input, and returns the id of the director. It works just fine and is called `dbo.fn_GetDirectorID`.

I wanted to make an endpoint in my Web API to call this function get the `directorID` then send back the employee object of that director to my client. So I was looking for online resources and I came across [this](http://anthonygiretti.com/2018/01/11/entity-framework-core-2-scalar-function-mapping/) I was like wow it's possible so let's try it out so I followed their tutorial I now have a `GetDirectorID` database function in my context like the link described

```
[DbFunction("fn_GetDirectorID", "dbo")]
public static int GetDirectorID(int id)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Then in my controller I was going to do something like this

```
[HttpGet("GetDirector/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetDirector([FromRoute] int id)
{
    var directorID = KPContext.GetDirectorID(id);

    var director = await _context.Employees.FindAsync(directorID);

    if (director == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(director);
}
```

but when I call the I throw the error because I get to the throw new `NotIMplementedException`, but I am not sure what to do here because the tutorial is saying this should call your function and work. Also I did do

```
int directorID = KPContext.GetDirectorID(id)
```

Can anyone help? I would greatly appreciate it.

I also just tried this

```
 [HttpGet("GetDirector/{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetDirector([FromRoute] int id)
        {


            var director = await _context.Employees.FindAsync(KPContext.GetDirectorID(id));

            if (director == null )
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(director);
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scalar functions like this can only be used inside LINQ to Entities query (cannot be executed client side, must be a part of SQL query).

Which means you cannot use `FindAsync`, so use `FirstOrDefaultAsync` or `SingleOrDefaultAsync` instead:

```
var director = await _context.Employees
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == KPContext.GetDirectorID(id));
```

This also has advantage over `FindAsync` that you can eager load (`Include` / `ThenInclude`) related data if you have such.

Also please note (not mentioned in the link) that if the scalar function is defined in a class other than the target `DbContext` derived class, it won't be registered automatically, so you'll need to add something like this to your `DbContext` derived class `OnModelCreating` override (if it's not the `KPContext` class of course):

```
modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(() => KPContext.GetDirectorID(default(int)));
```

For more info, see [Database scalar function mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.0#database-scalar-function-mapping) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I would try a linq query because I don't think pure EF is supported yet.

```
   [HttpGet("GetDirector/{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetDirector([FromRoute] int id)
    {
        var director =  from p in _context.Employees where p.EmployeeId == KPContext.GetDirectorID(id) select p;

        if (director == null )
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(director);
    }
```

this should get you what you need let me know if it works for you!! cheers and have a good day.

Comment: it is supported see @Ivan Stoev answer but this does work and got me what I wanted thank you for the